# How would you estimate the total price of a city with probability sampling?

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

There is a website where I can search for each and every price of a property (mostly houses) and I have list of 272 streets (which also consists of avenue, lanes, boulevard and etc) in the city. I have stratified them by street types and I have to sample about 160 streets in total for 95% Confidence interval and 5% margin of error.

Unfortunately, each and every streets has about 20~30 houses per streets and it would take awful lot of time to record all prices for those houses and it would also be inefficient.

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could give me a suggestion on what to do next or instead.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to estimate?

Comment: I am attempting to estimate the total value of land of a city. I am just wondering what part of the city can I actually sample to get an estimate of the city's value.